# Javascript calculations dynamically with no submit button

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I am pulling an item from a database, taking the cost and a user defined quantity and displaying a total. My goal is to have 25+ rows of supplies the user can calculate and add a grand total at the end. I am having trouble calculating the cost * quantity without refreshing the page and losing all other data. I am fairly new to javascript and I can't see why this isn't working for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updatesum(cost, quant, tot) {
    var qty = document.getElementsByid(quant).value;
    var price = document.getElementsByid(cost).value;
    document.getElementById(tot).value = (price * qty);

}
</script>

<cfoutput>
<cfform>
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td colspan=3>Supplies</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Supply</td>
        <td>Cost</td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td>Total</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><cfinput type="datefield" name="date_01" id="date_01"></td>
        <td><cfselect name="supply_01" onChange="">
                <option value="0"></option>
            <cfloop query="supplies">
                <option value="#supplies.id#">#supplies.supply#</option>
            </cfloop>
            </cfselect></td>
        <td><cfinput type="integer" name="unitCost_01" id="unitCost_01" value="" onChange="updatesum(unitCost_01, quantity_01, total_01"></td>
        <td><cfinput type="integer" name="quantity_01" id="quantity_01" onChange="updatesum(unitCost_01, quantity_01, total_01)"></td>
        <td><cfinput type="integer" readonly="yes" name="total_01" id="total_01" value=""></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</cfform>  
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: From briefly reading, it seems you're overriding the total with each input field, so once you change the 2nd input field, you delete the previous value

Comment: What is `document.getElementsByid()`?

Comment: Also good point, it's document.getElementById().  Case sensitive.

Comment: Check again - you got it right once and wrong twice.

Comment: Jumped on the question too quickly.

Comment: It's nice to display a total.  However, without a submit button, what do you intend to do with the data in these form fields?

Comment: Not sure the `ColdFusion` tag is valid on this question?

Answer (score 2):

You're not passing string element id values to your function:

```
    <td><cfinput type="integer" name="unitCost_01" id="unitCost_01" value="" onChange="updatesum('unitCost_01', 'quantity_01', 'total_01'"></td>
```

You should always have your browsers developer console open so that you can check for errors.

Also as some comments have noted, it's `getElementById()`, with "Element" singular.

Comment: True, also helps to have the dev. console open because then this would have jumped right out at you.